# Open an Excel Workbook within another Excel Workbook and then fill a Formular in this workbook

Tags: excel, macros, excel-2010, vba

I have an Excel Document and from this document I read some value and would like to insert these into another Excel workbook. I would like to open the workbook in the existing workbook then search for the specific field and set the values. How can I open such an additional workbook? and then set the values?

Best regards

Matthias

Comment: Try the [Workbooks.Open method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195811.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

assuming you know a little VBA, here is a framework to get started.

```
Sub copyBetweenWorkbooks()

    Dim wkbkA As Workbook
    Dim wkbkB As Workbook
    Dim copyValues As Range
    Dim directory As String, fileName As String, i As Long, j As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    directory = "c:\test\"
    fileName = Dir(directory & "yourspreadsheet.xls")

    Set wkbkA = ThisWorkbook
    Set copyValues = wkbkA.Sheets({ put sheet here}).Range({put range here})
    Set wkbkB = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName)

    With wkbkB

        'do your stuff here

    End With

    'close your stuff if you need to
    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much, but I still haven't understand on which workbook should I use the code? On the start or target workbook?